# change from Statements to PreparedStatements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a simple code which sending some info into mysql.

```
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement stmt;

        Properties connInfo = new Properties();
        connInfo.put("user", "Main");
        connInfo.put("password", "poiuyt");
        connection  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ABCNews", connInfo);


        String sql = "insert into abcnews_topics VALUES (null, '" + text_topic + "');";
        stmt = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

"text_topic" it`s variable with my info.
this code i have in cycle, and in each step the value of my variable (text_topic) changes.

and i want to use Prepared Statements instead my decision. 
how to do it?

Comment: There's plenty of examples on the internet, didn't you search at all?

Comment: Of course i search, but i always gets error in my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create the connection (unchanged)
Properties connInfo = new Properties();
connInfo.put("user", "Main");
connInfo.put("password", "poiuyt");
Connection connection  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ABCNews", connInfo);

// Prepare the statement - should only be done once, even if you are looping.
String sql = "insert into abcnews_topics VALUES (null, ?)";
PrepatedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

// Bind varaibles
stmt.setString (1, text_topic); // Note that indexes are 1-based.

// Execute
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parameterize your SQL, and call `prepareStatement`:

```
String sql = "insert into abcnews_topics VALUES (null, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    statement.setString(1, textTopic);
    statement.execute();
}
```

(The try-with-resources statement will close the `PreparedStatement` automatically. If you're using Java 6 or earlier, use a try/finally block to do it yourself.)

Note that I've changed the `text_topic` variable to `textTopic` to follow Java naming conventions, renamed `stmt` to `statement` to avoid abbreviation, and also moved the declaration of `statement` to the assignment. (There's no point in declaring it earlier: try to limit scope where possible.)